# Why are these elements unaligned?

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment

I am creating a search bar & button form with jquery like this:

```
var search_list_item = $("<li />");

var search_form = $("<form />", {
    name: "search_form",
    class: "search_form"
});

var search_input = $("<input />", {
    type: "text",
    name: "search_input",
    class: "search_bar"
});

var search_button = $('<input'
    + ' type="submit"'
    + ' value="&#128269;"'
    + ' class="search_button"'
    + ' name="search_button"'
  +' />');

search_form.append(search_input);
search_form.append(search_button);
search_list_item.append(search_form);
```

The CSS is set with this

```
.search_bar{
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: rgb(204, 204, 204) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;
    border: 1px solid rgb(178, 210, 203);
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.search_button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
    font-family: 'EntypoRegular';
    color: #5f615c;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1px;
    padding: 0px;        
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    left: 15.4%;
}
```

The HTML comes out looking like this:

```
<li>
    <form name="search_form" class="search_form">
        <input type="text" name="search_input" class="search_bar"/>
        <input type="submit" value="" class="search_button" name="search_button"/>
    </form>
</li>
```

But the end result looks like this:

[image]

Why is the search bar and button not lined up?

Comment: Maybe because of `line-height`. You should use your dev tools and be able to spot it why, playing with CSS rules

Comment: try giving them both `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: Set font-size: 100%; instead of font-size:30px; for .search_button.

Comment: Yeh, probably shouldn't have line-height of only 1px for the button. I find usually all the elements on the same line should have the same line-height, and that height should be large enough to accommodate the largest element.  From there, padding & margin to adjust individual elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decrease the `search_button` `font-size:30px` to `font-size:15px` [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/EzeM6/)

```
.search_button {

    font-size: 15px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set font-size: 100%; instead of font-size:30px; for .search_button

```
.search_button {
cursor: pointer;
border: 0px;
background-color: #d4d4d4;
font-family: 'EntypoRegular';
color: #5f615c;
font-size: 100%;
line-height: 1px;
padding: 0px;        
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
left: 15.4%;
 }
```